# How to add cover pages to appendices?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, chapters, appendices

For my thesis, I need to have appendices preceded by a cover page.

From school manual:

[image]

As of now, I have

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
...
\begin{appendices}
\input{appendix.parallel.tex}
\input{appendixdistortioncheck.tex}
\input{appendix.code.tex}
\end{appendices}
```

Each file starts with a `\chapter{Blah}` line.

The appendices themselves don't show up too well,

[image]

perhaps because I needed to reformat the chapter headings. The TOC shows up well.

(I tried using `\part{...}` instead of `\chapter{...}`, and it does create a cover page for each appendix,

[image]

but now the TOC is messed up.)

[image]

What would you advise? Thank you!

Comment: Your example is not compilable. Just remove the `\input` instructions and add some blind text preceeded by a chapter. This will show your problem properly. (`\begin{document}`and `\end{document}` are missing too.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply add  a patched version of the `\@makechapterhead` macro (which is responsable for creating the chapter headings) to the `\appendices` macro which will be called when using the `appendices` environment via `\g@addto@macro`. This patch is locally bounded because it will be applied inside the environment.

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@makeappendixhead#1{%
  \null\vfill%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vfill
    \clearpage
  }}
\g@addto@macro\appendices{\let\@makechapterhead\@makeappendixhead}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{No Appendix}
\lipsum
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

### Original version of `\@makechapterhead`

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

*(From latex.ltx)*

Comment: Ruben, it worked beautifully. I will study it to see what it is doing. (What's the best way to say thanks? the comment box says it is not meant to say thanks.)

Comment: On TeX.SX saying thanks is equivalent to upvote an answer. And it is also completely sufficent to do so. If you have questions on the solution that may be of general interest feel free to ask them as follow up questions. You can literally mark them as such. Minor issues may be resolved by searching this site or just google, *or* visiting the chat. Maybe I will be around...

Comment: Ruben, a followup question: by deleting \huge\bfseries and \Huge\bfseries, and adding a \MakeUppercase the A, B, etc. appendix headings became of normal size uppercase font (as in page 30 & 32 of initial screenshot). However, would you how can I make the main APPENDICES be all in uppercase and normal size? (as in page 29). Is there an option in the appendix package? Thank you in advance.