# How to change format of Appendix page name?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, appendices

This is a followup question to [How to add cover pages to appendices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/how-to-add-cover-pages-to-appendices?rq=1) . This screenshot shows the school requirements.

[image]

This minimal example comes from Ruben's solution to the previous problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@makeappendixhead#1{%
\null\vfill%
{\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \MakeUppercase \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vfill
    \clearpage
  }}
\g@addto@macro\appendices{\let\@makechapterhead\@makeappendixhead}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{No Appendix}
\lipsum
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

From Ruben's solution, the only thing missing is that the main APPENDICES heading (page 29 in screenshot) should be Uppercase and in normal size font (instead of huge and bold, as it is right now.)

What I understand so far:

The appendix package manual, page 7, shows this bit of code that seems to be formatting appendixpagename ,

```
\newcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
\clear@ppage
\thispagestyle{plain}%
\if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
\null\vfil
\markboth{}{}%
{\centering
\interlinepenalty \@M
\normalfont
\Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
```

This last line seems to do the formatting. It would seem that deleting the `\Huge` `\bfseries` and adding `\MakeUpperCase` should do it, but how do I wrap the code to add it to the tex document?

Or perhaps this whole approach is wrong. Please advise!

Comment: If you want to use that code on your document, insert it in your preamble surrounded by `\makeatletter <insert here> \makeatother` and use `\renewcommand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `\renewcommand`. As the name implies this is for redefining an existing macro, in this case `\@chap@pppage`. Add to your preamble, between the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

```
\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
  \clear@ppage
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \MakeUppercase \appendixpagename\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
  \fi
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
}
```

This is the complete (you had only included part of it in your question), old definition of `\@chap@pppage`, except that `\Huge \bfseries` is swapped with `\MakeUppercase`, as you yourself said.

If you don't want the start page for the appendices to appear in the table of contents, remove the `toc` option from the `appendix` package. If you want the ToC entry but you don't want the page number, add `\noappendicestocpagenum` to the preamble, after loading `appendix`. Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\noappendicestocpagenum

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@makeappendixhead#1{%
\null\vfill%
{\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \MakeUppercase \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vfill
    \clearpage
  }}
\g@addto@macro\appendices{\let\@makechapterhead\@makeappendixhead}

\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
  \clear@ppage
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \MakeUppercase \appendixpagename\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
  \fi
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{No Appendix}
\lipsum

%\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip\scshape Appendices \hfill \par} 
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Torbjørn, but something suprising (and even desirable) happened -- the main "Appendices" is now gone from the Table of Contents. (appendices A B are still there). As a workaround, I now added a \addtocontents{toc}{\scshape Appendices \hfill \par} line right before  \begin{appendices}. I say desirable because in fact I did not want that particular "Appendices" to be followed by dots or a page number.

Comment: @JuanZuluaga See my updated answer about the ToC entry.