# Custom title page for appendix

Tags: pdftex, report, appendix

I'm struggling with developing custom report class which reflects current requirements in the company. The goal is to encourage people to use LaTeX as main tool for reporting technical stuff. I would like to lower the entry threshold as much as possible. That's why class which takes care of all formatting seems to be a good idea. I'm almost there but need your support to solve problem related to custom cover page for each appendix. With current code I achieved this:
[image]

But I want to get this (optional figure in frame, ToC will go to another page):
[image]

I know this looks rather like cover page for main document but... anyway.

My class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myreport}[2018/08/29 My report LaTeX class]

\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[onecolumn, 10pt]{report}

\RequirePackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[toc, title]{appendix}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{etoc}
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%*********************************************************
% CUSTOM COLORS
%*********************************************************
\definecolor{MyBlue}{RGB}{0,65,101}
%*********************************************************
% SECTION REDEFINITION
%*********************************************************
\renewcommand\chapter{\@startsection {chapter}{1}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{MyBlue}}}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{2}{\z@}%
    {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{MyBlue}}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{MyBlue}}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{MyBlue}}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

%*********************************************************
% COUNTERS FOR FIGURES AND TABLES INCLUDE SECTION NUMBER
%*********************************************************
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} %depth for numbering
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}

%*********************************************************
% CUSTOM APPENDIX 
%*********************************************************

\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendices}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendix}


%redefinition of appendices environment from 'appendix' package
%this set up ToC depth
\let\oldappendices\appendices
\def\appendices{\oldappendices\etocdepthtag.toc{mtappendix}\etocsettagdepth{mtchapter}{none}\etocsettagdepth{mtappendix}{subsection}}


%*********************************************************
% TITLE PAGE
%*********************************************************
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%

\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}


        \bfseries
        \huge Main Title Of The Document
        \vskip.5in
        \LARGE Task title
        \vskip.2in
        \vskip.2in
        \LARGE Rev no
        \vspace{10cm}   
    \end{center}
\newpage
}

%*********************************************************
% HEADER AND FOOTER STYLE
%*********************************************************
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\footrule}{{\color{MyBlue}\vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth \hrule width\headwidth height \footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{3pt}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{red}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\footnotesize \textcolor{MyBlue} {\vskip.3cm TaskNo XXX \ - Rev.XXX}} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\footnotesize \textcolor{MyBlue} {\vskip.3cm Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
```

And example report which uses class above:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{myreport}

\begin{document}

\maketitle          %creates custom cover page
\tableofcontents    %creates main table of content
\newpage            %start first chapter from new page

%**************************  INPUT DOCUMENT CONTENT  **************************************
%******************************************************************************************
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text in main document.

%**************************  APPENDICIES  *************************************************
%****************************************************************************************** 


\begin{appendices}  

\chapter{Additional information}
\localtableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
Some text
\section{Section 2}
Some text

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This is simplified version but I believe it's enough to show the case.

Obviously, I tried to do it myself before asking for your help but I'm here so result is known :)

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149110/how-to-add-cover-pages-to-appendices) seems to be similar topic but I was not able to make it working for me. 
I would appreciate your comments. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find where to put the cls file ? If yes have a look at --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: @jsbibra why asking about cls file location? I have submitted class and document which uses the class. My question is only about customization of appendix title page.